# How to retrieve messages from dmsMessageTable of a Device Controller Using SNMP

Tags: snmp, mib, snmp4j

I am working on NTCIP/SNMP Protocol I was able to connect to the device controller using one one of the MIBBrowser and was able to walk through the different objects(OIDS) loaded through a MIB File. However,When I do a walk over the dmsMessageTable I can see only two messages(again through object IDs) being retrieved but the Device controller has more than two messages. The Messages being retrieved are default one provided with the device.

Can anyone help in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the correct primary index (the second last node of the OID)? This node corresponds to the message memory type. For changeable messages the index should be 3 or 4.

You can retrieve the number of messages  for the memory type, (for example, for changeable messages use dmsNumChangeableMsg - 1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.5.2.0) and then the last node of your OID should correspond to the message number in that type of memory bank.

EXAMPLE:

For the first message in changeable memory:
1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.5.8.1.3.3.1

For the second message in volatile memory:
1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.5.8.1.3.4.2